# French and Italian are Related: Linguistic Knowledge in the 12th-14th Centuries

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, tosfot

In [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28858/1659) answer to a question that concerned the ways in which languages change and evolve, @SethJ made reference to a sugya that discusses the differences between different dialects of Aramaic, and a corresponding Tosafot that evidences an awareness of different Romance languages belonging to the same language family. I am trying to find this sugya (and this Tosafot), but with no avail. Does anybody know which passage SethJ was referring to?

(I have already asked this by means of a comment on SethJ's answer, but since he doesn't know I figure that asking it again as its own question might draw it to the attention of a broader range of people.)

Comment: I started to look it up, didn't find it, and forgot to go back to it. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I may have remembered more detail than actually exists. I think I found the Tosafoth, which refers to observable differences in La'az in different countries (but doesn't specify). I'm going to update that answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Gemara and Tosafoth in question. As I explain in my [revised answer there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28858/5):

> In the 7th chapter of Bava Kama ([Bab. 83a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=83&format=text)) the Gemara quotes a
>   Baraitha that mentions the language  of "Sursi", and there is a
>   commentary by Tosafoth explaining that "Sursi" is a dialect of Aramaic
>   spoken in Eretz Yisrael. To address the obvious question of why it has
>   a different name, Rabbeinu Tam says: "לפי שמעט משתנה כעין לשון לעז
>   שמדברים אותו לשון צח במדינה אחת יותר מבאחרת"; (loose translation) "It
>   had changed enough to be considered its own language, similar to
>   La'az, which is more or less pure depending on where you are."